# .onload and .onerror both are executing together

Tags: javascript, onload, onerror

I am beginner in javascript and has this problem can someone please explain what's the reason behind it.

**Problem:**
js.onload and js.error both getting called when script has error...when i am doing this js.onload function get called even when script has error....but if script doesn't has any error .onerror function is not being called..so problem is only with js.onload function

```
const loadScript1 = (src,func)=>{
let js = document.createElement("script");
js.src = src; //setting src attribute
js.onload = func(null,src);
js.onerror = func(new Error("Error in Script: "),src) //this function get executed when script js has error while loading
document.body.append(js);}
```

but Somehow if i declare a function and then calling func function inside it it solves the problem for example

**this is working:**

```
const loadScript1 = (src,func)=>{
let js = document.createElement("script");
js.src = src;
js.onload = function(){func(null,src);}
js.onerror = func(new Error("Error in Script: "),src) //this function get executed when script js has error while loading
document.body.append(js);}
```

can someone please explain **Why????**

**This is full code:**

```
const loadScript1 = (src,func)=>{
    let js = document.createElement("script");
    js.src = src; //setting src attribute
    js.onload = func(null,src);
    js.onerror = func(new Error("Error in Script: "),src) //this function get executed when script js has error while loading
    document.body.append(js);
}

const loadedsc1 = (error,scrpt)=>{
    if(error){
        console.log(error+scrpt);
        return;
    }
    alert("script loaded : "+scrpt);
}

//invalid script
loadScript1("https://cdn.jxxsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",loadedsc1);
```

Comment: `js.onload = func(null,src);` = execute func(null,src) immediately and assign its return value to js.onload.

Comment: The code that you say is working is not, in fact, working. It always executes the error function.

Comment: then how can i pass arguments while assigning the function?

Comment: The exact same way you did for `onload`: `js.onload = function(){func(null,src);}`

Comment: thank you guys....got my answer <3